# Matching column from 2 data frames and create a new column in the second data frame based on matches

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames.  They have uneven number of records.

**DF1:**

```
structure(list(subscriberid = c(1085369583, 1244038459, 1240958486, 
1088671175), cweAge = c(32, 30, 49, 30), cweGen = c("m", "m", 
"m", "m"), hwAge = c(60, 30, 47, 30), hwGen = c("f", "f", "f", 
"f"), cwe = c(1, 1, 1, 1), hw = c(1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("subscriberid", 
"cweAge", "cweGen", "hwAge", "hwGen", "cwe", "hw"), row.names = 453:456, class = "data.frame")
```

**DF2**

```
structure(list(subscriberid = c(1244038459, 1240958486, 1234200861
), mem_1_gen = c("f", "f", "m"), mem_1_age = c(32, 23, 12), mem_2_gen = c("m", 
"m", "f"), mem_2_age = c(38, 48, 12), mem_3_gen = c("0", "f", 
"f")), .Names = c("subscriberid", "mem_1_gen", "mem_1_age", "mem_2_gen", 
"mem_2_age", "mem_3_gen"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

They look like this:
**DF1**

```
    subscriberid cweAge cweGen hwAge hwGen cwe hw
453   1085369583     32      m    60     f   1  1
454   1244038459     30      m    30     f   1  1
455   1240958486     49      m    47     f   1  1
456   1088671175     30      m    30     f   1  1
```

**DF2**

```
  subscriberid mem_1_gen mem_1_age mem_2_gen mem_2_age mem_3_gen
1   1244038459         f        32         m        38         0
3   1240958486         f        23         m        48         f
9   1234200861         m        12         f        12         f
```

I want to add a 7 column `mem_1_cwe` in `DF2` ,which will have the data from `DF1$cwe` wherever there is a match in `subscriberid` AND `AGE` AND `GENDER`.

I have tried match with interaction:

```
df2$mem_1_CWE <- df1$cweGen[match(interaction(df2$subscriberid, df1$subscriberid),interaction(df2$mem_1_age, df1$cweAge))]
```

But since I have number of records in each data frame is different, I am getting the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, mem_1_CWE, value = c(NA_character_,  : 
  replacement has 1918 rows, data has 1915
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ans * length(l) + if1 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In ans * length(l) + if1 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: check `merge` or `left_join`

Comment: @Jimbou I do not want to use merge because my DF2 has 12 members, where I have to match cwe for each member. If there is a match then the value of the cell will be one otherwise 0.

Comment: Try `left_join(df2, select(df1,1:3,cwe), by = c("subscriberid","mem_1_age"="cweAge","mem_1_gen"="cweGen"))`

Comment: @Jimbou  Thank you...I have around 4000 records, but just only 1 record gets matched....there are atleast 250 matches when I physically verified

Comment: please add one physical match in your example data.